# How can i perfectly photoshoot clothing so all the details will be clear and look also like 3D?

Tags: photo-editing, clothing

I would like to know the best way to photoshoot clothing so it will be perfect to show on e-shop . The details of the clothing must be very clear and look like 3D.
Please let me know what i must use ( Devices ,Programms, Lighting) and how i will do it
Im attaching you aslo some photo to understand better what i want

[image]
.[image]

Thanks a lot

Comment: With 'look like 3D', do you mean that it looks as if someone is wearing the clothes, that is, that the clothes are 'filled' with a body? In the pictures you are showing, it looks as if the clothes are on a mannequin and that the mannequin has been retouched out of the final images.

Comment: "look like 3D" – [Anaglyphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaglyph_3D), though haven't seen them on any shopping sites.

Comment: I have heard before the ghost mannequin effect and maybe is an option but i haven't tried it yet. I heard also about some programs that you can transform a photo of a clothing into a digital one with very high resolution analysis or even create the clothing item in this program. Anyone know something about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the photography side these look 3d because they are.  One of the comments has already mentioned the ghost manikin effect where they are placed on a body but the body has been edited out.

The other most important thing is light.  In order to get the look you're after you need at least one larger light source that is going to provide the subtle shadows that will give it dimensions.

Equipment list:
Light source i.e. off camera flash
Diffuser (Preferably with a grid)
Transmitters/cable to connect to camera (you can skip this if you've rigged it up with a permanant light source)
Camera - nothing special, just needs to be able to work with the off camera light probably a second hand DSLR if you don't already have one.
Tripod would be handy if you see yourself doing lots of these